# Lightning component namespace error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, namespace

I have working code in an org without a namespace. Trying to migrate the code to an org with a namespace seems to be causing a lot of trouble on the lightning side. Everything in APEX in fine.

Basically, this bit of code works fine :

```
<aura:attribute name="InvoicableData" type="CreateInvoiceController.Invoice_Wrapper"/>
```

Where Invoice_Wrapper is an inner class of CreateInvoiceController.

What is not working though, is whenever a namespace is added. I keep on getting the same error which is :

```
Failed to save undefined: No TYPE named apex://CreateInvoiceController.Invoice_Wrapper found : [markup://azurgroup:CreateInvoice]
```

I tried adding the namespace to the attribute (following this [salesforce article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_reference.htm)) but the same error keep on appearing.

I had a similar problem in visualforce which could be solved by saving the class directly over using the Developer Console but with Lightning I currently have no choice.

I read somewhere that taking the class outside would probably solve the problem, but since its working without the namespace there must be something silly I am missing.

Anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a bug I believe.

The workaround that I was able to apply was to move inner class into its own class .

In short for namespaced org if you are working with lightning components move wrapper class to its own class .

Comment: While I still dont know why it worked without a namespace, it does work when I move the main wrapper class out of the controller. So I'll just mark this as the answer.